# Synce Firestore data to google sheets

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I am trying to sync data from my Firestore to my google sheets.

I have created a serviceAccount and saved the credentials in JSON file

The functions folder succesfully deploys however the function is executing with errors.

Below is my index.js

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions')
var admin = require('firebase-admin')
var { google } = require('googleapis')
var sheets = google.sheets('v4')
admin.initializeApp()

var spreadsheetId = '...'
var serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json')

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
  email: serviceAccount.client_email,
  keys: serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
})

var jwtAuthPromise = jwtClient.authorize()

exports.testFunction = functions.firestore.document('/scores/{docID}').onCreate(async snap => {
  if (snap.exists) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snap.data()))
    await jwtAuthPromise
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(
      {
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: 'new!A2',
        valueInputOption: 'RAW',
        requestBody: {
          values: [[obj['Player'], obj['Score']]],
        },
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells)
        }
      },
    )
  }
})
```

The cloud function triggers when any document is added to my `scores` collection, the data is then added to my google sheet.

When I manaually update my Firestore, these are the errors in my error log

```
testFunction Function execution took 2620 ms, finished with status: 'error'
testFunction Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted.
testFunction
Error: No key or keyFile set. at GoogleToken.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:115:23) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at /srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:13:71 at new Promise (<anonymous>) at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:9:12) at GoogleToken.getTokenAsync (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:110:16) at GoogleToken.getToken (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:64:21) at JWT.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:144:40) at Generator.next (<anonymous>) at /srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:22:71
testFunction
Error: No key or keyFile set.
    at GoogleToken.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:115:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:13:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:9:12)
    at GoogleToken.getTokenAsync (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:110:16)
    at GoogleToken.getToken (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:64:21)
    at JWT.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:144:40)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:22:71
testFunction Unhandled rejection
testFunction
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
testFunction
Function execution started
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gotten Functions to integrate with Google Sheets by creating a promise that uses the Json file and returns the authorization when I need it. This is a trimmed version of the method I used but you can adapt it to your needs:

```
// Helper to get authorization
// (You may need to add the Drive scope 
// if you want to add additional users permission to edit the file)
var clientPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = new google.auth.JWT({
            keyFile: 'my_key_file.json',
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 
                    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
        });

        resolve(client);
});

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
.document('myCollection/{addedDoc}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // do something with the new document
    // ...
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // You may not need this part but you can use a new promise here if you need it.
        console.log(snap);
        resolve(true);

    }).then(result => {
        return clientPromise;

    }).then(auth => {
        sheets = google.sheets({
            version: 'v4',
            auth: auth,
        });

        // do something with the sheets variable
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give this ago